# Improve Regular Expression for a specific pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working on a project where I analyze a text generated by Tesseract. In that text, I am looking for a code that has the following syntax: **CI XXXX**. However, since Tesseract often misrecognizes words, I created the following regular expression:

`[\s]?..\s?(\S\d{3}|\d\S\d{2}|\d{2}\S\d|\d{3}\S)[\s]?`

This regular expression looks for a code composed of two letters followed by an optional space and finally four digits with the possibility that one of the digits is a character. I did not include "CI" at the beginning of the regular expression because Tesseract often does not recognize it. This regular expression works for most cases, as shown in the image below, except for the case of "**nCI1234n**".

So my question is : can we improve this regular expression, or should I use an if statement in my code (C#) to look for possible four digits and then take the previous two characters?
[image]

Comment: based on your description you don't want to support the first digit to be a character, so you can change your regex to: ``[\s]?..\s?(=\d\S\d{2}|\d{2}\S\d|\d{3}\S)[\s]?``

Comment: It looks like you need `[\p{Lu}.]{2}\s*(?:\p{Lu}\d{3}|\d\p{Lu}\d{2}|\d{2}\p{Lu}\d|\d{3}\p{Lu}|\d{4})`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F4F8UM/1).

Comment: Your regular expression works perfectly, could you share it as an answer with a quick explanation if possible ? @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
[\p{Lu}.]{2}\s*(?:\p{Lu}\d{3}|\d\p{Lu}\d{2}|\d{2}\p{Lu}\d|\d{3}\p{Lu}|\d{4})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F4F8UM/1).

The main point here is to allow matching a dot since the OCR software you are using mistakes `I` with `.`. It is possible to just use `C[I.]` instead of `[\p{Lu}.]{2}` if that assumption is correct. Note that the `\p{Lu}` matches *any* Unicode letter.

*Details*:

- `[\p{Lu}.]{2}` - two  occurrences of an uppercase letter or a dot
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:\p{Lu}\d{3}|\d\p{Lu}\d{2}|\d{2}\p{Lu}\d|\d{3}\p{Lu}|\d{4})` - four digits, or three digits and one uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            string input = "The si.I 1234vr & SCI 1234e  inC. 1234des a CI X234heet, fCI*1X34l RefCI 12X4nce, and HCI 123Xp.  You nCII234n.";
            string pattern = @"(?'match'[A-Za-z]{2}\s?(\d{4}|[A-Za-z]\d{3}|\d[A-Za-z]\d{2}|\d{2}[A-Za-z]\d|\d{3}[A-Za-z]))";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
            foreach (Match match in matches.Cast<Match>())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["match"].Value);
            }
```

Comment: It doesn't work for all the cases :/

Comment: @Hibou : I based it on your description.  If it is not working than your description is not correct.  Are the two character always letters?  Is there always one space (optional)?

Comment: No, the two characters are not always letters and the space is optional. @jdweng

Comment: @Hibou : Which case doesn't work?

Comment: it works only for "SCI 1234e" where it detects CI 1234.

Comment: I fixed issue.  Missed fact that one of the digits could be a letter.  What characters are allowable.  Right now code is using only letters.